# Suggestions to improve representation of data

Tags: tables

DISCLAIMER: I'm a bit of a LaTex newb, so I apologise for probably doing something wrong or stupid - I'm asking to become better.

I have a number of processes which all have three properties: a name, a short expression and a (often) very long expression. I would like to tabulate this information to give a overview over it. I do not think the solution I have found does so optimally. My attempt is below. Maybe it is better to have the process name and the short property in the same cell as in
[image]

,to best use the fact that the long property often needs multiple lines,
but I can not figure out how to do so. I think also a little more space between the lines would make it easier to read. How do you guys think the data is represented in the best way?

Edit: I guess my question is a bit vague, so to make it more answerable: Can I achieve the double line narrow first column and wide second column as in the inserted image?

This is my attempt (by cutting and pasting answers from this site):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand \IG  {\text{IG} }
\newcommand{\dilog} {\text{Li}_2}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % for '\RaggedRight' macro (allows hyphenation)
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X} 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ c c  Y @{}}
Process   &  $\kappa(\theta)$ &  Integral $\int_t^T \kappa(f(s)) \d s$   \\
\midrule    
$\IG(\delta,\gamma)$-OU   &  $\frac{\delta \theta}{\sqrt{\gamma^2-2\theta}}$  &    $\frac{\delta}{\lambda }  \bigl (\sqrt{\gamma^2 - 2 f(t,z) }- \sqrt{\gamma^2 - 2 i z \rho }  \bigr ) +  \frac{2 \delta g(z) }{\lambda \sqrt{2 g(z) - \gamma^2} }     \Bigl (\arctan \sqrt{ \frac{\gamma^2-2 i z \rho}{2 g(z) -\gamma^2} }  - \arctan \sqrt{ \frac{\gamma^2-2 g(z) \rho}{2 g(z)-\gamma^2} }    \Bigr ) $   \\ 
$\Gamma(\alpha,\nu)$-OU  &  $\frac{\nu \theta}{\alpha - \theta}$   &  $\Bigl (\alpha \ln  \frac{\alpha- f(t,z)}{\alpha - i z \rho  } + g(z) \lambda (T-t)   \Bigr ) \times  \frac{\nu}{\lambda ( \alpha- g(z) ) }$ \\
OU-$\IG(\delta,\gamma)$  &  $\delta (\gamma- \sqrt{\gamma^2 - 2 \theta }) $   &  $\delta \gamma (T-t) + \frac{2 \delta}{\lambda }\bigl (\sqrt{\gamma^2- 2 f(t,z) } - \sqrt{\gamma^2 - 2i\rho z} \bigr )  
                                              + \frac{2 \delta \sqrt{2g(z) - \gamma^2}}{\lambda}  \Bigl (\arctan \sqrt{ \frac{\gamma^2-2 i z \rho}{2 g(z) -\gamma^2} }  - \arctan \sqrt{ \frac{\gamma^2-2 g(z) \rho}{2 g(z) -\gamma^2} }    \Bigr ) $ \\
OU-$\Gamma(\nu,\alpha)$ &  $-\nu \ln (1-\frac{\theta}{\alpha} ) $ &   $-\nu \lambda^{-1} \Biggl( \dilog \frac{c e^{-T \lambda }}{c+\alpha -i \theta  \rho } -\dilog  \frac{c}{c+\alpha -i \theta  \rho } +\lambda  T \log \frac{\alpha +c-i \rho  \theta }{\alpha }  \Biggr )$   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can change space between lines using `\\[1ex]` for example.

Comment: @Sigur thanks for the tip! I will definitely use that idea :)

Comment: You might find $\displaystyle \frac{\nu}{\alpha}$ more attractive than just $\frac{\nu}{\alpha}$.

Comment: not relevant to the question itself, but the initial minus sign in the last line is a binary minus, so place `{}` before it in the input to get the correct spacing.  also, it's "traditional" to place operators at the beginning of a continuation line, instead of at the end of the continued line; this applies to a couple of `\times` operators.  (russian typography is different; there, the operator is placed in both locations to indicate continuation.)

Comment: @JohnKormylo and barbara beaten - I appreciate these tips a lot! I will try to introduce them in my practice! :)